# Capybara rspec script not executing in describe blocks

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, rspec, capybara

I am new to Ruby in general. I am trying to learn capybara with selenium to do testing for our company website.

My code was working before I put them into describe blocks. But I needed to wait for the page to load after sign in. I did some research and found that expect method is the way to go but they only work in it blocks I think.  Now when I run ruby testscript.rb, browser does not even open. Below is the code:

```
require 'timeout'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec/matchers'
require 'capybara/session/matchers'
require 'capybara/node/matchers'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)

describe 'login process', :type => :feature do
    it 'signs me in' do        
        visit 'https://testwebsite.com'
        find_by_id('login_form')
        fill_in('username', with: 'testuser')
        fill_in('password', with: 'testpw')
        find_by_id('Login').click
        expect(page).to have_content('phSearchInput')
    end
end

describe 'search install product', :type => :feature do
    it 'searches product' do
        fill_in('phSearchInput', with: '6109302')
        find_by_id('phSearchButton').click
        within "SVMXC__Installed_Product__c_body" do
            click_on "6109302"
        end
    end
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Feel free to provide alternatives to solve the wait for page load problem. I do not want to use sleep. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All `describe` does is define the tests, it doesn't actually run them.  To run the tests you need to launch them with rspec, so instead of `ruby testscript.rb` you need to run

```
rspec testscript.rb
```

Additionally, assuming phSearchInput is the id of an input, your waiting expectation would need to be

```
expect(page).to have_field('phSearchInput')
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_css('#phSearchInput')
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:id, 'phSearchInput')
```

`have_content` (alias for have_text) checks for visible text on the page, not elements.

One last comment - Capybara will create it's own default session, if you mean to use that you can remove your Session.new line.  If you want to manually manage sessions then you need to call all of Capybaras methods on that session.  `session.visit(...)`, `session.fill_in(...)`, `expect(session).to ...`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is running now. But I am getting a NoMethodError on 'expect'. I think I added all requires. Any ideas?                                                This is the line: expect(page).to have_field('phSearchInput')

Comment: @shen Assuming you're running a modern version of RSpec it sounds like you need to require 'rspec' or 'rspec/expectations' before 'capybara/rspec' and maybe configure RSpec too.

Comment: I just installed everything yesterday so I believe everything should be modern. I dont have 'rspec' or 'rspec/expectation'. I have  'capybara/rspec/matchers' and it's before  'capybara/rspec' but it is still not working. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add the especially requires

Comment: It looks like it's working now. But it's not really waiting to the field to show up. It just says there are no matches for this field and the test ends in a failure?

Comment: which test? which line? Is the login working? What does the HTML look like?  This is really becoming a different question